# I want to translate strings in data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm translating my project. I translate js/json to HTML but I made v-for instead of copying 4 same HTML code made this :

```
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <div class="box my-5" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
            <div class="innerBox">
              <router-link to="/sixthPage">
                <div class="card Fcard d-flex  flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="padding: 1rem 2rem !important">
                  <p>{{item.title}}</p>
                </div>
              </router-link>
              <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I wanna translate `{{ item.title }}` but **I dont using the I18n plugin.** I translating myself **I asking for how can I translate `{{ item.title }}` using v-for.**

```
import en from "../locales/en.js";
import tr from "../locales/tr.js";
export default {
    el: '#app',
    mixins: [en, tr],

    data () {
        return {
            items: [
                {title: 'Protect Privacy',},
                {title: 'Bypass Censorship',},
                {title: 'Faster Internet'},
                {title: 'I do not want to specify',}
            ],
            lang: window.navigator.language,

        }
    },
    components:{
        Header
    },
    methods: {
        translate(prop) {
            return this[this.lang][prop];
        }
    },
```

When translating in HTML usage like this : `<h2>{ translate('name') }}</h2>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h1> {{ translate(item.title) }} </h1>
 data(){
     return{
        items[ {title: 'SeventhPageTitle'} ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could define `translate` as computed property that returns a function which translates the item title :

```html
 <p>{{translate(item.title)}}</p>
```

script :

```js
    computed: {
        translate() {
            return (prop)=>this[this.lang][prop];
        }
    },
```